# organizing array from least to greatest c++

Tags: c++

Hi I'm working on a project that lets the user input numbers and the code organizes them in order of least to greatest and tells how many of each number was input. I'm having problems with the organizing of least to greatest and counting how many of each number are inputed

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>

void main(){
    double a[30];
    double e[30];
    double b;
    int c[30];
    int d;
    double f=0;
    cout << "how many input values [max 30]:";
    cin >> d;
    cout << "enter " << d << " numbers:"<<endl;
    for(int x=0; x<d;x++){
        cin >> a[x];
        c[x]=0;
    }
    cout << endl;
    for(int y=0; y<d;y++){
        if(a[y]>=f){
            f=a[y];
        }
    }
    for(int z=0;z<d;z++){
        if(a[z]){
            c[z]++;
        }
        if(a[z]>=a[z+1]){
            e[z]=a[z];
        }
    }
    cout << "numbers       count"<< endl;
    for(int printloop=0;printloop<d;printloop++){
        if(a[printloop]>0){
            cout << e[printloop]<< "               " << c[printloop] << endl;
        }
    }
    cout << "max value:" << b << endl;
}
```

Comment: You probably should use a vector instead of an array. That way, you don't have to limit your user to 30 numbers.

Comment: You should use better variable names to make it easier to reason about what your doing. Also use comments to tell the reader what your (trying) to do. The problem is as far as I can see in the 2nd loop which doesn't sort and the 3rd loop which doesn't do what I think your thinking.

Comment: What is the number range  ?

Answer (score 1):

Solution base on std::map http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map, note the `Compare` template argument and C++11 (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    std::map<int, int> count;

    int n;
    std::cout << "How many numbers ? ";
    std::cin >> n;

    std::cout << "Now enter " << n << " numbers : ";

    for(auto i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        int tmp;
        std::cin >> tmp;
        count[tmp]++;
    }

    for(auto const& elem : count )
        std::cout << "Element " << elem.first << " count : " << elem.second << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```